# Flutter can't find "telephony" in release mode,but foreground is normal in release mode,I added a decorator on background func,it's still not working

Tags: flutter, telephony

I am using Telephony plugin to develop a SMS app, and according to the similar solution, I added a decorator on the top of the background handler at the top level, then run it in release mode,

after running, debug mode is normal, and foreground is also normal in release mode,only both "background" and "terminated" are incorrect

```dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> onBackgroundMessage(SmsMessage message) async {
  debugPrint("onBackgroundMessage called");
  ............
}
```

after adding, it's still not working and appeared the same Dart error message:

> "Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:telephony/telephony.dart' not found."

I have already added the decorator `@pragma('vm:entry-point')`, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem,just need to change or add a git link in pubspec.yaml,

```
telephony: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/definev/Telephony.git
      ref: develop
```